What programming language is better for data science?
I'm a student who is currently learning Python and Java. I'm very interested to learn about data science and machine learning as well as deep learning.
Which of Java and Python is more useful for me?

If you are starting off with learning data science and machine learning. I would recommend picking one language - specifically python.
In my opinion, Data science/ML is a large field and trying to learn multiple languages adds extra levels of complexity to an already challenging field. It would be better to focus on mastering the concepts using a single language and then expanding to other languages once you have the basics.
I would recommend starting with python because there are already many DS/ML libraries that exist, in addition, there are a lot of resources online that you can leverage with respect to learning DS using python.
Some popular libraries include Pandas, Scikit-Learn, and PyTorch - there are many many more.
